# Android Room - Query to return LiveData but limited by userId

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am trying to limit my search results by userId. So for example

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM exampleTable WHERE userId = :userId");
LiveData<List<Users>> getRecordsByUserId (long userId);
```

REPOSITORY

```
 private long userId;
 private LiveData<List<WorkoutLogsAllPojo>> weeklyWorkoutLogs;
 public WorkoutLogsRepository(Application application) {
         weeklyWorkoutLogs = workoutLogsDao.getWorkoutLogsWeekly(userId);
 }
 public LiveData<List<WorkoutLogsAllPojo>> getWorkoutLogsWeekly() {
    return weeklyWorkoutLogs;
 }
```

VIEWMODEL

```
 private long userId;
 private LiveData<List<WorkoutLogsAllPojo>> weeklyWorkoutLogs;
 public WorkoutLogsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
 weeklyWorkoutLogs = workoutLogsRepository.getWorkoutLogsWeekly(userId);
 }
  public LiveData<List<WorkoutLogsAllPojo>> getWorkoutLogsWeekly() {
    return weeklyWorkoutLogs;
 }
```

ACTIVITY

```
  private void getWorkoutLogsWeekly() {

    workoutLogsViewModel.getWorkoutLogsWeekly(userId).observe(this, new Observer<List<WorkoutLogsAllPojo>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<WorkoutLogsAllPojo> result) {

                }
        }
    );
}
```

My current code returns 0 records. If I remove the userId stuff from the code it will return all records. Could someone please help me implement the userId constraint into this code so the query will only return the records linked to that userId.

Comment: why do you have a dash in the where clause ? `userId - :userId`

Comment: Maybe a typo in your WHERE clause: `userId - :userId`.  Don't you want `=` instead of `-`?

Comment: That was a typo, I hand typed that query out. Its an = in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this:

Updated the Viewmodel and Repository to:

```
 public LiveData<List<WorkoutLogsAllPojo>> getWorkoutLogs(long userId) {
    return WorkoutLogs = workoutLogsRepository.getWorkoutLogs(userId);
}
```